# In my application I am getting the full image path. I want to get only the path

Tags: java, android

> String imgpath ="/mnt/sdcard/joke.png";
>   Output:"/mnt/sdcard

Comment: please explain your question properly....

Comment: So, you basically want to strip out the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.

As per https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/

```
String imgpath ="/mnt/sdcard/joke.png";
String path = imgpath . substring(0, imgpath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
```

Or using `java.io.File`

```
String imgpath ="/mnt/sdcard/joke.png";
String path = new File(imgpath).getParent();
```

I prefer the latter, but it's really up to you.